# Consuming .Net Webservice list function

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to return a list from a web method. 
I am trying to consume the service, I am having problem.
I want to show the values in 3 different labels, I dont know how can I do that.

Given the following web method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<Employee> empWeb(int Id)
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        List<Employee> emplist = new List<Employee>();

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id,FirstName,Salary from Emp where Id='" + Id + "' ", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {

            emp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]);
            emp.Name = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
            emp.Salary = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Salary"]);


        }

        con.Close();
        emplist.Add(emp);
        return emplist;
    }
```

Employee Class

```
    public class Employee
{
    int iId, isalary;
    string sname;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return iId; }
        set { iId = value; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return sname; }
        set { sname = value; }
    }
    public int Salary
    {
        get { return isalary; }
        set { isalary = value; }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to consume in my aspx page. Code of my aspx page is as follows:-

```
    public void GetWebEmp()
{
    localhost.Service1 obj = new localhost.Service1();
    var lstwebemp = obj.empWeb(1);

}
```

In this function I want to show values like

```
Label1.Text=Emp.Id

Label2.Text=Emp.Name

Label3.Text=Emp.Salary
```

but it is showing all values in `lstwebemp` 
Please Help.

Comment: @rahulaggrawal Can you check lstwebemp value in this statement `var lstwebemp = obj.empWeb(1);`

Comment: @SurajSingh Inside lstwebemp there are all values of Id, Name and Salary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Label1.Text=lstwebemp[0].Id.ToString();

Label2.Text=lstwebemp[0].Name.ToString();

Label3.Text= lstwebemp[0].Salary.ToString();
```

---

```
Check if you are able to access properties like this .
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but its not working. After lstwebemp "Id" is not coming

Comment: Suraj - I suspect you need a ToString() on there

Comment: The code is giving error:'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @SurajSingh Inside Label it is showing "localhost.Employee" and when I put lstwebemp[1]), it gives error Index out of Range

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution

```
        foreach (var emp in lstwebemp)
    {
        lbl1.Text =Convert.ToString(emp.Id);
        lbl2.Text = Convert.ToString(emp.Name);
        lbl3.Text = Convert.ToString(emp.Salary);

    }
```